# Why isn't the LinkedIn icon included in the social:profileViewer component?

Tags: visualforce

I'm using the  component to replicate the social network icons beneath a Contact profile.  I just realized that one of the icons, LinkedIn, is missing and I have no idea why.

I suspect the answer to this is "because LinkedIn connectivity is still in Beta" but Spring 12 documentation doesn't mention that the standard Social Accounts and Contacts is different to the Visualforce component.

It just says "A new Visualforce component is available, so you can easily add the Social Accounts and Contacts viewer to your custom account, contact, and lead detail pages. You don’t need to use this component for standard account, contact, or lead pages."  Likewise, the [component documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_social_profileViewer.htm) doesn't make any mention of this.  As LinkedIn is very important for the business, I can't imagine not having this icon in the Contact Detail page.

Comment: Can be a bug in SFDC itself .Can you raise a case with SFDC support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official response from SFDC:

> I would like to inform you that currently Linked in icon is not
>   available in (Custom visual force page) as there is some issue in
>   Linked in and salesforce contract.